# Why use def power(x) and math.pow(x,n)?

Tags: python

Here is what I needed to accomplish:

> Write Python script that will print out integers 1 through 10, and
>   their square roots and cube roots.
>
> Use the list: `range (1,11,1)` to define the numbers.
>
> Use `math.pow(x,n)` function.
>
> To calculate square roots and cube roots, define function power (`def power (x)` etc.) that calculates these values.
>
> Then, print them out in the form `x`,`sqrt(x)`,`cuberoot(x)`, one
>   below the other (`print` command should be outside of the `power`
>   function).
>
> Utilize the `for` command  [e.g., `for i in range (1,11,1):` ] and at
>   each value of `i` call the function `power(x)` to complete the
>   calculation and return the result, and then print the result out on
>   the screen.

here is my code:

```
list=range(1,11,1)

for i in list:
    print i
for i in list:
    print i**.5
for i in list:
    print i**(1.0/3)
```

So obviously I didn't use any of the required commands, because when I tried using math.pow it kept telling me the string argument must be a string or number.  I need help, I am lost.  At least point me in the starting direction.  Because even though my code works I know it won't be accepted.

Comment: Maybe you can show the code that didn't work, with a minimal, but complete example so we can try it, and see the exact same error as you saw.

Comment: Show what you tried that used `def power`.

Comment: If you know what it won't be accepted....have you tried working something that WILL be accepted?

Comment: I think "one below the other" means you should actually print them one below the other, not in groups by power

Comment: FYI, the math.pow() works correctly and the results are correct. Note that cube root is math.pow(i, 1/3).  You must be calling the function wrong. also make the loop for i in range(1, 11, 1): sqr, cube = power(i); print(i, sqr, cube) do not use the reserved keyword list as a variable

Comment: `list=` don't do that or you'll have trouble calling `list()` later in your code.

Comment: @sabbahillel - That'll work in Python 3, but in Python 2 (which the OP is using) it would need `math.pow(i, 1/3.)` (a situation the OP has handled in `i**(1.0/3)`).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 OK thanks. I did not see the python version. Since it is a comment that is too old to edit, I let your comment show that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutoring service.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint that by this

> To calculate square roots and cube roots, define function power (`def power (x)` etc.) that calculates these values

It doesn't literally mean `def power(x)`, it means `def sqrt(x)` and `def cuberoot(x)` that `return math.pow(x, <power>)` for each respective power.

`math.pow(x, n)` works correctly, though you will need `import math`.

---

Should also be noted that

```
for i in list:
    print i
for i in list:
    print i**.5
for i in list:
    print i**(1.0/3)
```

Should probably be written like so (except with the correct code by following the instructions). Most importance: Don't override the `list` function with a variable.

```
for i in range(1, 11, 1):
    print i
    print i**.5
    print i**(1.0/3)
```

Or maybe this since it says "in the form `x,sqrt(x),cuberoot(x)`, one below the other"

```
for i in range(1, 11, 1):
    print i, i**.5, i**(1.0/3)
```

Comment: Yes!  No one told me it wasn't to be taken literally.  No wonder it never worked.

Comment: It might mean `def power(x):` that accepts `x` and either prints or returns the original number, its square root, and cube root. This is something that the instructor should clear up.

Comment: @user5833593 I wrote it taking it literally so that power returned the tuple sqr and cube as return sqr, cube after they were calculated in power and it still worked. taking it literally would not hurt it. Inside the loop you can print it as print(i, sqr, cube)

Comment: If you carefully read the instructions, that's what the "etc." meant after `power(x)` and the references to these methods at "print them out in the form `x`, `sqrt(x)`, `cuberoot(x)`"

Comment: @sabbahillel you're speaking a foreign language here.  It took me 2 hours just to produce what I did.  Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: @sabbahillel - remember this is Python 2

Comment: Or maybe the "etc." means the definition of the `power` function. I think you're assuming too much here.

Comment: I'm harping on this because making multiple separate functions to wrap various calls of the same basic function with different arguments emits quite a strong code smell.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - Maybe. I agree the instructions are a bit vague on that front. It is possible that the `power(x)` function returns the 3 values

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - It seems like an intro-course type problem, so code-smells are often overlooked based on my school experience.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I believe you're right.  She wants us to know how functions work with different arguments.  But her accent is strong and this is only week 2.  So part of my difficulty was in knowing what the assignment was actually asking of me.

Comment: @cricket_007 this is computational physics.  We are using python to code physics equations, so its an intro/physics class.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that you are not sure how to use the power definition and return the tuple. You should read the definition of def and return but here it is.

```
import math
def power(x):
    sq = math.pow(x, 0.5)
    cub = math.pow(x, 1.0/3)
    return(sqr, cub)
```

Now call from inside the loop with

```
(sqrt, cube) = power(i)
print(i, sqrt, cube)
```

Note that the names inside the definition and for the call are different **only** to show that they are in different scopes. It would work even if you gave them the same names.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This will give me an opportunity to learn what is being inputted.  I will heed your advice and read the definition of def.

Comment: @cricket_007 typo fixed

Comment: Also, wouldn't `return sqr, cub` work, then `sqrt, cube = power(i)`. And a tuple doesn't need printed, so `print i, sqrt, cube`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes  the parentheses are not required, however, even in Python 2 I use them anyways so that it is more readable (at least as far as trying to form habits)

Comment: @cricket_007 I am not sure why the edit did not go through when I tried it. Thank you for doing it as well.

Comment: @sabbahillel So where do I use the range function then?  This is where I get confused.  I don't see how to use it.

Comment: @user5833593 - Use it like I did in my answer, just replace, for example, `i**.5` with the function call of `sqrt(i)`

Comment: I just realized you could also do `return (x, sqr, cub)`, then simply do `print power(i)`

Comment: In Python 2, `print(i, sqrt, cube)` will print out a `tuple` e.g. `(1, 1, 1)` rather than printing out each value separated by a space e.g. `1 1 1`.

Comment: I can't get it to say anything other than: i is not defined

Comment: Well, then define it somewhere, such as in `for i in xrange(1, 11):`.

Comment: I did that, but obviously I did it wrong: `sqrt, cube = power(i)`
`for i in xrange(1,11,1):`

Comment: Did you try to refer to it before defining it?... I'd say you could use another few minutes with your course materials.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Of course I could use more time, but unfortunately this course isn't designed for that.  So I will put in my hours and learn, but right now it's frustration, which is why I came for help.

Comment: Again, you are attempting to use a variable, `i`, before you've told the interpreter what value it represents. I'm sorry that your course isn't designed to give you time to learn, but SO isn't designed to be a tutoring service for those who don't have time to read course materials.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I just told him what to do inside the loop. I saw in the original question that he had done it correctly. (sigh)

Comment: @user5833593 Look in your original question how you used the for loop.

Comment: @sabbahillel I got it!  Thank you very your patience.  And now that I have learned more about stackoverflow I will make sure only to use when I have a specific error and not for generalities.

Comment: @user5833593 Make sure to register so that you can answer when you learn more and vote for answers that you like. That is how many of us got started. (:-) I also come here to see what other people ask and learn from the questions and answers.